# Update text field with zodiac after choose birthdate

Tags: php, forms

I have a form with a `date` field where I choose the user birthdate (`dob`).

```
<input type="date" max="2098-12-31" name="meta[dob]" id="meta[dob]" size="25" value="<?php echo $meta['dob'] ? $meta['dob'] : ''; ?>">
```

What I need to achieve is to update the `input` zodiac sign right after I enter the birthdate AND before I save the form.

This is my code to find the zodiac sign of the user:

```
<?php
    $time  = strtotime($meta['dob']);
    $day   = date('d',$time);
    $month = date('m',$time);
    $year  = date('Y',$time);
    if(($month==1 && $day>20)||($month==2 && $day<20)) { $mysign = "aquarius";}
    elseif(($month==2 && $day>18 )||($month==3 && $day<21)) { $mysign = "pisces";}
    elseif(($month==3 && $day>20)||($month==4 && $day<21)) { $mysign = "aries";}
    elseif(($month==4 && $day>20)||($month==5 && $day<22)) { $mysign = "taurus";}
    elseif(($month==5 && $day>21)||($month==6 && $day<22)) { $mysign = "gemini";}
    elseif(($month==6 && $day>21)||($month==7 && $day<24)) { $mysign = "cancer";}
    elseif(($month==7 && $day>23)||($month==8 && $day<24)) { $mysign = "leo";}
    elseif(($month==8 && $day>23)||($month==9 && $day<24)) { $mysign = "virgo";}
    elseif(($month==9 && $day>23)||($month==10 && $day<24)) { $mysign = "libra";}
    elseif(($month==10 && $day>23)||($month==11 && $day<23)) { $mysign = "scorpio";}
    elseif(($month==11 && $day>22)||($month==12 && $day<23)) { $mysign = "sagittarius";}
    elseif(($month==12 && $day>22)||($month==1 && $day<21)) { $mysign = "capricorn";}
?>
```

How can I update this, right after I choose the user birthdate (`dob`) in the date field above?

```
<input type="text" name="meta[zodiac]" id="meta[zodiac]" size="25" value="<?php echo $meta['zodiac'] ? $meta['zodiac'] : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? What's your exact question about this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I've updated the question. Hope I made it clear. Thanks!

Comment: You need Ajax to communicate back to PHP, but it's very simply to do with JS and `addEventListener`

Comment: @Justinas Please share an example

Comment: What have you tried to make this work? Why do you need to run this algorithm using PHP? Wouldn't it be more easier to calculate the corresponding sign in JS?

Comment: @NicoHaase As long as it work I don't mind. Can you share an implementation example?